# rosserial RosServoControl arduino with two servos

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!!

I am trying to go further with the basic example of Ros Serial with Arduino and a Servo. In this example, the publisher asks for an angle where to drive a servo. I am trying to do this with two servos, but the only thing I can do is to drive both to the same position. I need some tip for how to write two parameters in Ros, so each servo goes to its position.
The code I have for the moment is as follows:

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

Servo servo, servo2;

void servo_cb( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg){
servo.write(cmd_msg.data); //set servo angle, should be from 0-180
servo2.write(cmd_msg.data);
digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));  //toggle led
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub("servo", servo_cb);
ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub2("servo2", servo_cb);

void setup(){
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

nh.initNode();
nh.subscribe(sub);

servo.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
servo2.attach(3);
}

void loop(){
nh.spinOnce();
delay(1);
}

Can anyone help me please??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61266/rosserial-rosservocontrol-arduino-with-two-servos/) by [flipmurry](https://answers.ros.org/users/4728/flipmurry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
try this:
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot/tree/master/MockBotSerial

Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flipmurry](https://answers.ros.org/users/4728/flipmurry/) on 2013-04-22**:
THank you!! I will try it tomorrow and I'll tell the result :)

**Comment by [flipmurry](https://answers.ros.org/users/4728/flipmurry/) on 2013-04-22**:
You just saved my day!! I wrote a code similar to yours and it works as I needed :D thank you very much Christian

**Comment by [flipmurry](https://answers.ros.org/users/4728/flipmurry/) on 2013-04-22**:
Hi Christian, just one more question! When you write:

rostopic pub /servo1 std_msgs/UInt16 $i$j

is there any way to send an angle to the servo2 in the same line??so I move both servos at the same time but different angles?

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-29**:
This link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ReHi,
good to know, that somebody can reuse my old code ;-)
"rostopic pub /servo1 std_msgs/UInt16 $i$j" was just a stresstest for my servos from bash...
I expect rostopic did not support multiple topic from a single line.
For performance reasons use python, lua or other languages for rapid testing.
Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flipmurry](https://answers.ros.org/users/4728/flipmurry/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thank you very much, I will try some things and I will post if I have any interesting result!